# Typescript async/await converts to yield error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm trying to do some async/await

```
private onSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): Promise<void> => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.takerAddress)
    try {
      const balance = await someAsyncFn()
      console.log('BALANCE:', balance)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
         this.props.onSubmit(this.state.takerAddress);
         try {
             const balance = yield someAsyncFn(), console, log; // line 30
             ('BALANCE:', balance);
         }
 @ ./src/components/Search.tsx 4:15-32
 @ ./src/components/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Form.tsx:29:73
    TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Form.tsx:30:14
    TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Form.tsx:30:18
    TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Form.tsx:30:19
    TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
```

here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it compiles very weird here and I'm not sure why. Is this because I'm missing something in tsconfig?

Comment: Do you have any other loaders running? That certainly looks like the code has become corrupted somehow, since `yield someAsyncFn(), console, log` makes no sense based on the input code.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I have this in webpack.config: 
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },

Answer (score -3):

The tsconfig is targeting `es6`. The keywords `async/await` were introduced later. So under the hood, the typescript compiler uses helpers based on generators to emulate this behavior.
Try bumping the target option if you can in your project.